# Refactor anchor tag to button due to ng-disabled not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this anchor tag defined:

```
<a ng-disabled='placeOrderDisabled()' href='@Url.Action("Order","ShoppingCart")?deliveryMethod={{deliveryMethod}}' class="btn btn-primary">
     {{ placeOrderButtonText }} <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

In Firefox and Chrome, the anchor tag is still clickable though, and I understand from other answers that this is by design, and I need to use a button instead.

Please advise how I need to refactor the above code to use a button element since the button element cannot have the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="placeOrderDisabled()" ng-click="clickFn()">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
```

on JS file. I assume @Url.Action is object function inside the controller.

```
$scope.clickFn = function () {
  var url = $scope.Url.Action('Order','ShoppingCart') + '?deliveryMethod=' + $scope.deliveryMethod;
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't refactor your code**. You can still achieve the disabled behavior with the anchor tag using the CSS.

```
a.disabled, a[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what
>   circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the
>   target of mouse events. When this property is unspecified, the same
>   characteristics of the visiblePainted value apply to SVG content.

**See a working example below:**

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);
```

```css
a.disabled,
a[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="sa" ng-init="disableButton = false">

  <a ng-disabled='disableButton' href="" class="btn btn-primary">
     I'm an anchor button <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="" ng-click="disableButton = !disableButton">Disable the anchor button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, but the button remains clickable in Chrome and Firefox (even though the cursor changes to the "No Entry" cursor.